# Remove /page directory or /page.htm within .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Is there away within .htaccess file to redirect or hide a directory or page and have it display as Page Not Found, or an error?

I currently have an active Blog and do not want to remove it, but have /blog hidden if anything was to go to it.

Comment: So to be clear you want www.example.com/blog to redirect to a error page ?

Comment: @error2007s that is exactly what I would like to do! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a error page for example by name "404.html". And add this rule to the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^blog$ /404.html? [L,R=301]
```